# How can I show all users I follow?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have models:

**Profile** mode

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", through=UserFollowing, related_name="followers",
                                           verbose_name=_("following"), symmetrical=False)
```

And **UserFollowing** model

```
class UserFollowing(models.Model):
    following_from = models.ForeignKey("Profile", related_name="following_from", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       verbose_name=_("Following from"))
    follow_to = models.ForeignKey("Profile", related_name="follow_to", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  verbose_name=_("Following to"))
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

How can I show all profiles I follow?
How Can I setup query set to show al followers and followed Profiles?

```
Profile.objects.filter... ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all profiles you are follow, try this:

```
Profile.objects.get(pk=request.user).following.all()
```

Or:

all profiles you are follow:

```
Profile.objects.get(pk=request.user).following_from.all()
```

all profiles follows you:

```
Profile.objects.get(pk=request.user).follow_to.all()
```

Comment: The request is underlined in red - I'm trying use this in a ListView.

Comment: are you add this query in method or in field "queryset"?

Comment: I made method:
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Profile.objects.get(pk=request.user).follow_to.all()
        return queryset
But request is red underlined. I've tried with self.request.user but than heve error:
Field 'id' expected a number but got <SimpleLazyObject: <Profile: admin>>.

Comment: try with "self.request.user.id" instead of request.user

Comment: I've tried but it isn't work correctly - i have empty query set (i have followers and following in database)

Comment: I made:     def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).get(
            pk=self.request.user.id).follow_to.all() BUT STILL HAVE EMPTY QUERYSET :(

Comment: keep in mind this query returns UserFollowing objects not Profile

Comment: This give me nothing:
    `def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Profile.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.id).follow_to.all()
        return queryset`
I'v try in template 
`{% for profile in object_list %}
    {{ profile.username }} <br>
{% endfor %}`
i have empty page nothing in template..

Comment: because this is not Profile object, try  {% for follow in object_list %} {{ follow.follow_to.username }} <br> {% endfor %}

Comment: It's for sure bad solution... It gives me only my nickname in result... not username i follow. Something is wrong with this (with queryset)

Comment: this is proper for that query {% for follow in object_list %} {{ follow.following_from.username }} <br> {% endfor %}

Comment: Ok, I'll check for the moment!

Comment: and if you want to get list of users you are follow use "....following_from.all()" not ".follow_to.all()"

Comment: yes, yes.. everything vork now.. thank you for your patience :)

Comment: One thing.. not excactlu its what I want.. How can I chceck ANOTHER USER followers and followed user? Now its only my followers and following.. i want lists of another user followers and followings

Comment: replace self.request.user.id in query with id of user you want to check Profile.objects.get(pk=user_id)

Comment: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f256275e3a0>.

Comment: Or: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f521d7f63a0>

Comment: you must get id of user and put it to query instead of "user_id"

Comment: Yes but had user_id red underline... Tried user.id, Profile.pk

Comment: where you try to make this query?

Comment: tried both: method and listview atribute queryset - always user_id is red underline

Comment: I;m tryin do this in ListView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228903/discussion-between-am0k-and-ryszard-orlikowski).

Comment: if you want get user id in ListView you have to pass pk variable in url

Comment: 'path("<slug:slug>/followers", Followers.as_view(), name="followers"),' I'm using slug in url..

Comment: if you use slug in url you must also use slug to get user. Try Profile.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])...

Answer (score 0):

You will want to filter with the current session authenticated user

```
Profile.objects.filter(following=User.id)
```

Comment: Not realy.TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable DeferredAttribute object

Comment: instead of filter ,which returns all related rows,you can try get,but you have to specify the pk of the user

Comment: Still not.. TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7ffb13e377f0>.

Comment: Profile.objects.get(following=User.id)

Comment: as above: TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7ffb13e377f0>